# Embed an application icon using WPF and F#

Tags: wpf, f#, icons

How to embed an application icon into `application.exe` using WPF and F#? I did not find it anywhere.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841947/changing-f-application-icon) you can see how to handle icons for WPF and F#

Answer (score 2):

I think the approach is the same for WPF and WinForms, which in F# means manually!

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181313/how-do-i-set-a-program-icon-in-visual-studio-2010/7181455#7181455) answer.

You could also looks at [FsEye's](http://code.google.com/p/fseye/source/browse/#svn/tags/1.0.0-final) source for reference (it's done in WinForms), see line 39 of [http://code.google.com/p/fseye/source/browse/tags/1.0.0-final/FsEye/FsEye.fsproj](http://code.google.com/p/fseye/source/browse/tags/1.0.0-final/FsEye/FsEye.fsproj#39), the file http://code.google.com/p/fseye/source/browse/tags/1.0.0-final/FsEye/IconResource.fs, and line 23 of [http://code.google.com/p/fseye/source/browse/tags/1.0.0-final/FsEye/Forms/WatchForm.fs](http://code.google.com/p/fseye/source/browse/tags/1.0.0-final/FsEye/Forms/WatchForm.fs#23)

Comment: You can add the icon to the project file using VS: just click Add New..., find the icon and remember to change the type to Embedded Resource.

Answer (score 2):

(Update: link is no longer alive -- removed)

Quote:

"Make a .rc file with the following line: 
1 ICON "icon.ico"

Then compile it with [rc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381055%28VS.85%29.aspx) and include the .res file in your project's properties page. 
You may also include .resources files in your project but the system will not pull the application icon from those."

Comment: This solution does not appear to work. Anyone have any success with this? I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: @battlebottle Yes. It works for me. What is the rc.exe output with /v key? If it writes something like "Writing GROUP_ICON:" and then unitelligible symbols you have a problem with UTF-8 signature. Simply delete the file and create it with echo command. rc.exe with /v key should write "Writing GROUP_ICON: 1"

Comment: the first link seems to lead to a malware site

Comment: @theimoswki Thanks for noticing. It was ok back then. I will remove it.